# Does Batman have a contingency plan for Alfred?

Tags: dc, batman

It's well established in comics and animation that Batman has contingency plans for immobilizing or neutralizing his various allies, should it become necessary.

Has there ever been any mention of whether he has such a plan in place for Alfred?

Comment: Well the thing is that Alfred can probably be taken out by a plain old beating, no need for Kryptonite or heavy artillery... But in the meantime, Alfred, with all he knows, coudl _wreck_ Batman's life indeed. I'venever had the impression Bruce thought Alfred could become a foe (although he thinks of everything, right). TLDR, very interesting question, +1.

Comment: Agreed @Jenayah. 1) Alfred is an old man in most of the comics, likely in his 60s maybe early 70s. Thus easily subdued by someone with Bruce's physique. 2) Alfred is practically a second father to Bruce, so it's highly doubtful he would do anything to hurt Bruce and vice versa. He made a promise to Thomas and Martha Wayne to care for their son. Compromising and hurting Bruce would mean shredding and breaking that promise, and destroying his own integrity. Alfred is not that kind of person.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan Alfred isn't that kind of person indeed, but Batman isn't planning for the "kinds of person" people _are_, but the ones they _could become_. There are telepaths, torturers, necromancers, whole lot of stuff out there in DCland which could make one turn, willingly or not. That's what Batman is being cautious about.

Comment: Truth, and there are the short, off-shoot series where Alfred DOES become compromised and turns into something evil (I forget the name of the mini-series of comics issues).........but in regards to the Canon series, we also need to remember Alfred's own background from before his time with the Waynes. It's highly likely he'd be able to withstand great amounts of torture/attempts to turn him against Bruce. Granted, he doesn't have the special martial training Bruce received with the League of Shadows, but he did have YEARS of training and experience to resist attempts to turn him.

Comment: Well, he could stop Alfred's supply of arthritis medication!

Comment: @Rebel-Scum - Or just fire him. Then he'd be a homeless elderly man

Comment: Why would he need one? Most versions of Alfred are incredibly old and one of the few people Bruce has in his life that he loves and cares for.

Comment: Unless Alfred uses the super-pill in the Injustice comics, there is no difficult way for Bruce to take him down. Depends on the version of the character. For instance, Michael Caine's Alfred could easily be taken out by Christian  Bale. Jeremy Irons has some tactical knowledge, but I don't really think that would matter for Battfleck. On the other hand, the psychological trauma Bruce would get would be unparalleled. When Superman allegedly killed Alfred in the Injustice comics, Bruce pretty much lost it. Imagine the same thing but if Alfred betrayed him,

Comment: I can't put this as an answer because I don't remember the reference, but I remember in one of the animations it was shown on the computer that Alfred had higher access computer levels than Batman.  In other words, Alfred IS the contingency plan for if Batman goes bad, and thus it would be inappropriate to set up the reverse.